# Having some issues with docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, flask, docker-compose

Im pretty new to flask , postgres and docker. I am trying to dockerize our application so that a new dev does not have to worry about installing python depenedencies to start developing. I currently have two containers, one for the flask app and one for the postgres db. 
The issue I am having is that when I put the two in a compose they cannot connect to each other. I have defined my own network to ensure that they are running on the same one but that still does not seem to solve the problem. When I run the flask app outside of a container and try to connect to the containerized postgres db I am having no trouble connecting and it works fine.

Any help would be much appreciated 
Thanks in advance

Dockerfile for the flask app

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.7

LABEL maintainer="uwblueprint"
LABEL org.label-schema.schema-version="1.0"
LABEL org.label-schema.name="elevate-api"
LABEL org.label-schema.vcs-url="https://gitlab.com/uwblueprint/elevate-api/"
LABEL org.label-schema.vendor="UW Blueprint"

## Copy source and environment-config files.
COPY app/ ./app/
WORKDIR /app

COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock ./

## Install external dependencies.
RUN apk add --no-cache libpq


## Install application dependencies.
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual build-deps \
        gcc musl-dev postgresql-dev libffi-dev && \
    pip3 install --upgrade pip pipenv gunicorn && \
        pipenv --python 3.7 && \
        pipenv install --system --deploy && \
    apk del build-deps

EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

Docker Compose File

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  database:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/uwblueprint/elevate-api/postgres:latest
    build:
      context: ./external/postgres
      cache_from:
        - registry.gitlab.com/uwblueprint/elevate-api/postgres:latest
        - postgres:10.5-alpine
    container_name: database
    env_file: ./external/postgres/configs/.env
    volumes:
      - postgres.data:/var/lib/postgresql/data # persist data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - "api_net"

  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      - "api_net"
networks:
  api_net:
volumes:
  postgres.data:
```

Python SQL Alchemy Code

```
import os
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app import app

# Make sure that DB_PASS is an environment variable:
##if 'DB_PASS' not in os.environ:
##    raise EnvironmentError("Could not find environment variable 'DB_PASS',")

##user = os.environ.get("DB_USER", "robot")
user ="fakeUser"
password = "fakePassword"

##password = os.environ["DB_PASS"]
host = os.environ.get("DB_HOST", "0.0.0.0")
port = os.environ.get("DB_PORT", "5432")
name = os.environ.get("DB_NAME", "elevate")

# Configure flask-sqlalchemy.
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "postgresql://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s" % (
    user, password, host, port, name
)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

# TODO: Find the optimal pool recycle time for PostgreSQL.
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE"] = 7200  # in milliseconds

# The db object is aware of the Flask application lifecycle, and will do things
# like close the database session when a Flask request ends.
#
# This saves a lot of headaches compared to the plain SQLAlchemy library, where
# I kept running into issues about database-session related objects trying
# to access the session when I had closed it prematurely (due to SQLAlchemy's
# lazy-loading data acess methods).
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Comment: Could you share your python code how do you connect to database?

Comment: Yeah sure one second. I also found that when I try to run a ubuntu container on the same network and try to nc to it, I still have no luck. But when i do it externally I am good to go

Comment: I think this is the same as this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47648792/communicating-between-different-docker-services-in-docker-compose

Comment: I don't think so. As their issue was that they were using the wrong ports to try and ping their containers

Answer (score 0):

Set DB_HOST to "database" which is the name of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Inside docker-compose you can make connection between services by service names. You can read about this in [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

Set `host` or `DB_HOST` environ to `database`. `127.0.0.1` won't work.